# h2database select only matched rows if two column comparison is true

Tags: java, h2

I am writing a simple javafx application that has combobox,checkbox,tableview control. The checkbox text is "Show short product list only" . I want, if checkbox is selected then this will get all the data from h2 Database based on comparing two columns and set items for the tableview. Such as select only matching rows if QTY column is less than ShortPrd.This is how i am pushing the data to table:

```
public void fillTable(ActionEvent actionEvent,String sqlQuery){

    try {
        System.out.println("Executing "+sqlQuery);
        connection = SqlConnect.con();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String> namePro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("name");
        PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String> batchPro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("batch");
        PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String> expPro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,String>("exp");
        PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Integer> qtyPro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Integer>("qty");
        //PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Double> mrpPro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Double>("mrp");
        PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Double> amtPro = new PropertyValueFactory<TableData,Double>("amt");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(namePro);
        batchColumn.setCellValueFactory(batchPro);
        expColumn.setCellValueFactory(expPro);
        qtyColumn.setCellValueFactory(qtyPro);
        //mrpColumn.setCellValueFactory(mrpPro);
        amtColumn.setCellValueFactory(amtPro);
        Hyperlink rbutton = new Hyperlink("Done");
        while (resultSet.next()){

            String name = resultSet.getString("name");
            String batch = resultSet.getString("batch");
            String exp = resultSet.getString("exp");
            int qty = resultSet.getInt("qty");
            Double mrp1 = resultSet.getDouble("mrp");
            Double amt = resultSet.getDouble("rate");


            tableData.add(new TableData(name,batch,exp,qty,mrp1,amt, rbutton));


        }
        tableView.setItems(tableData);


    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        common.CustomException(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            common.CloseCon();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The check box event handler:

```
shortCheckBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if(shortCheckBox.isSelected()){
                onlyShortCheckBox.setDisable(true);
                sqlQuery = "select * , CASE WHEN QTY<SHORTPRD THEN 'Only Display' ELSE 'No Display'  END FROM ITEMS;";
                tableView.getItems().clear();
                fillTable(null,sqlQuery);
            }
            else{
                onlyShortCheckBox.setDisable(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Everything working fine, just i can't think of the sql query.

I tried condition based query :

```
select * , CASE WHEN QTY<SHORTPRD THEN 'Only Display' ELSE 'No Display'  END FROM ITEMS;
```

But it shows all rows, only difference is with extra columns with The text is on condition based. Which is going to set on the table that users don't want. here is the screenshot:
[image]

What is the right way to get the rows of only matched columns?

Comment: You mean a [where clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) ?

Comment: Anyway, i got working. solved!